# Easiest way to access unordered list ids as array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, html-lists

I have an unordered list; I am using DB ids as list-item ids; After the Submit button pressed, I want all ID's of my list-items to be presented as an Array in PHP. I am new to javascript; there are solutions available but can't really figure out proper solution.
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Please post the code that you've already tried.

Comment: ul id="songs-1"
foreach ($content as $val)
li id="{{ $value->a_id }}">{{ $value->file_name) }} /> li
endforeach
ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got html like this ...

```
<ul>
   <li id="1">
     item 1
   </li>
   <li id="2">
     item 2
   </li>
</ul>
```

... you can rebuild it like this (with hidden-tags) ...

```
<ul>
   <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="1" />
   <li id="1">
     item 1
   </li>
   <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="2" />
   <li id="2">
     item 2
   </li>
</ul>
```

.. then in PHP you can access it like this ..

```
$arrIds = $_REQUEST["ids"];  // array(1, 2)
```

PS:

I first missed you wanted it in PHP so here still as additional info how to do it in JS:

You can use the following code to get an array of ids fetched from the li-ids:

```
var ids = [];
$("li").each(function() {
   ids.push(this.id);
});
```

... or withouth jquery ...

```
var ids = []
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ ){
   ids.push(lis[i].id);
}
```

Comment: I might recommend `var ids = $('li').map(x => x.id).get()`

Comment: or without jquery: `var ids = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), x => x.id)` – keeping sure to provide adequate polyfill for `Array.from`

Comment: What if I have two unordered lists? One is actually fetching data from DB; other is used to generate a play-list by using drag n drop. Then all list-items will be indexed into array. So, first I guess I have to mention the ID of unordered list, so that it only fetch list-items from required one.

Comment: I was just about to use text-box hidden's; but want some clean implementation. I am good at DB side and custom scripting but javascript is my all time nightmare :{

Comment: I think going with hiddens here is the way to go

Comment: Yer dear Mr. Hans Gerber, you are right. Going to use hiddens. I am really thankful for your timely reply and interest. I wish I can order a cup of coffee for you ;)

Comment: @Junaid Shah I updated my post one more time. I corrected the hidden-inputs (just so nobody gets confused :))

Comment: Yes dear Hans Gerber; I already have incorporated. Someone having basic idea of array can understand indexing. Yet again I am thankful for your interest and time spared for me.Happy Coding :)